# Issue Displaying Data from useState in return() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render data from a GET request with useState in React. I am able to console log my data, which is structured like  this:

{id: 1, title: “title”, date_of_show: “date”, teaser: "Welcome to…”, card_image: "https://blahblahblah.jpg”, content: “asdfasd”}

I am trying to get this data to replace the hard-coded data in my return(). I have tried this a few different ways, as shown on the ‘episode’ and ‘card_image’ props in the  component below (episode={data.id} and card_image={data.card_image}).

However, I am not able to access the data from useState in the return() method. What am I doing wrong? Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


function App(){
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'http://localhost:5000/episode',
    );

    setData(result.data);
    console.log(result.data[0]);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

    return (
      <div className="episode-app-page" style={{ color: 'white' }}>
        <Logo />    
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' render={() =>
              <div id="link-container">

                <Link to="/e1">
                  <Post
                    episode={data.id}
                    card_image={data.card_image}
                    title="title goes here"
                    date_of_show="April 20, 2020"
                    teaser="This is the..." />
                </Link>

              </div>
            } />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <MeetingFormModal />
      </div>
    );
  }



export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is an array and you are trying to access it like an `object` in `

If you want to just use the first element of your api response, then do this:

```js
<Post
episode={data[0].id}
card_image={data[0].card_image}
title="title goes here"
date_of_show="April 20, 2020"
teaser="This is the..." />
```

you can also use `data.map` and loop over the array and render all the `<Post>`s

Also a quick side note: Don't specify the callback function of  `useEffect` to be `async`. The return type of useEffect is a function. If we use async then it returns a promise.

Comment: I had tried calling the index earlier, as you mention - {data}[0].id} - but that returns the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". I'm trying to use map(), like in the above suggestions, but am also getting an error for that approach ("TypeError: data.map is not a function"). Do you have another idea for how I could implement map()?

Answer (score 0):

If `result.data` in `fetchData` is an array, you need to use the map method.

```
<div id="link-container">
{data.map((item,index)=>(
  <Link to="/e1">
  <Post
    episode={item.id}
    card_image={item.card_image}
    title="title goes here"
    date_of_show="April 20, 2020"
    teaser="This is the..." />
  </Link>
)}
```

Comment: When I tried this, I received "TypeError: data.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You are doing great, only issue is you must be using map when you have array of records. In your render method `<Route exact path='/' render={() =>` replace with this code and do consider extracting this to new component later.

```
{data.map((episode)=>{
const { id, card_image: cardImage } = episode;

return (
<div>
  <Link to=`episodes/${id}`>
  <Post
    episode={id}
    card_image={cardImage}
    title="title goes here"
    date_of_show="April 20, 2020"
    teaser="This is the..." />
  </Link>
</div>
)}}
```

Comment: When I implement this, I get the "TypeError: data.map is not a function" error. I know the data I am accessing through the fetch request is an array with an object inside, like: [{ }]. How would I access that?

Comment: can you post your data here? I can help you further if that happens. Also it can be because data is not fetched yet, try to show loading icon when data has not been fetched yet it will be undefined until you receive the data from the server which can lead to this error. Also try to put debugger and check what is coming up in `record.data` first.

Comment: The data will be an array of objects. I have just one object to use right now just for testing, but it looks like this: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Episode #1",
        "date_of_show": "April 20, 2020",
        "teaser": "Welcome to the first …",
        "card_image": "https://cdn.technologynetworks.com/tn/images/thumbs/jpeg/640_360.jpg",
        "content": "Today we are going to… "
    }
]

Comment: I haven't targeted all of the keys in the object in my posted code, but I will. I was just trying to get the "id" and the "card_image" to render before I ran into issues. each value is going to be a string, and the ID will be a number.

Comment: Can you try adding `console.log(data)` before your return in the component? That should provide you with data you are getting, it should have been set to undefined at some point to throw this error.

Comment: Okay - I put in that console log. My console shows two responses for that line (line 39 in my editor) - the first returns empty and the second returns with all of the [{ }] and contains all of the keys and values. I wonder why the data returns empty the first time, and if that has anything to do with the data not being rendered?

Comment: For now just try with:
if (!data || (data && data.length === 0)) {
  return <div>Fetching data...</div>
}

You should go with more elegant solution in future though. This should be enough to render what you want for now.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I'm refactoring this into a separate component now.

Comment: Good to hear that it's working for you now! Good luck and happy coding!